# What's the most efficient way to flatten a DOM using lxml?

Tags: python, dom, xpath, data-structures

## Context

The Python 2.7 function below traverses a DOM using etree and xpath and builds a flattened list representation of the DOM. At each node, it checks if the current element has a class that should be ignored - if so, it skips the element and its children.

```
import re
from lxml import etree

ignore_classes = ['ignore']

def flatten_tree(element):
    children = element.findall('*')
    elements = []
    if len(children) > 0:
        for child in children:
            if child.attrib.get('class') in ignore_classes:
                continue
            else:
                for el in get_children(child):
                    elements.append(el)

    elements.insert(0, element)

    return elements
```

## Question

**How can I improve this?** There has to be a more elegant and more efficient way. If I'm writing a nested `for` loop, I must be doing something wrong.

## Example

This document:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header class="ignore">
            <h1>Gerbils</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <p>They like almonds. That's pretty much all I know.</p>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

Would turn into something like:

```
[ <html>, 
  <body>, 
  <main>, 
  <p> ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an XPath such as

```
In [24]: root.xpath('descendant-or-self::*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[@class="ignore"])]')
Out[24]: 
[<Element html at 0x7f4d5e1c1548>,
 <Element body at 0x7f4d5e1dba48>,
 <Element main at 0x7f4d5024e6d8>,
 <Element p at 0x7f4d5024e728>]
```

The XPath `descendant-or-self::*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[@class="ignore"])]` means

```
descendant-or-self::*          select the current node and all its descendants
  [                            such that
   not(                        it is not true that
     ancestor-or-self::*       it itself or an ancestor
       [@class="ignore"]       has an attribute, class, equal to "ignore"
   )]
```

---

To handle a list of class names to ignore, you could build the XPath using a bit of code.
For example, if `ignore_classes = ['A', 'B']` then you could define

```
conditions = ' or '.join([
    'ancestor-or-self::*[@class="{}"]'.format(cls) for cls in ignore_classes])
xpath = 'descendant-or-self::*[not({})]'.format(conditions)
```

so that `xpath` would equal

```
'descendant-or-self::*[not(ancestor-or-self::*[@class="A"] or ancestor-or-self::*[@class="B"])]'
```

Even though this looks wordy, using lxml's XPath engine should be significantly
faster than traversing the tree in Python.

---

```
import lxml.html as LH

html = """
<html>
    <body>
        <header class="ignore">
            <h1>Gerbils</h1>
        </header>
        <main class="ignore2">
            <p>They like almonds. That's pretty much all I know.</p>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>"""

def flatten_element(element, ignore_classes):
    conditions = ' or '.join([
        'ancestor-or-self::*[@class="{}"]'.format(cls) for cls in ignore_classes])
    xpath = 'descendant-or-self::*[not({})]'.format(conditions)
    return element.xpath(xpath)

root = LH.fromstring(html)
ignore_classes = ['ignore']
flattened = flatten_element(root, ignore_classes)
print(flattened)
```

yields

```
[<Element html at 0x7f30af3459a8>, <Element body at 0x7f30af367ea8>, <Element main at 0x7f30af2fbdb8>, <Element p at 0x7f30af2fbae8>]
```

Comment: Thanks! This works really well.

Two small things I ran into:
1. `return root.xpath(xpath)` should be `return element.xpath(xpath)`
2.  In order to avoid getting the entire flattened document, the xpath for element has to be included in `xpath` before the class conditions

Comment: @pg_gargleblaster: Thanks for the corrections. I've modified the XPath so that you do not need to include the xpath for the element before the class conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DOMImplementation.createDocument with parameters.